# Django: cannot import name check_password

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a custom user model, but I'm getting the following error on my login page when trying to authenticate a member

`ImportError at /members/login/
cannot import name check_password`

I know the [check_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password) method exists, but not sure what I'm missing. What am I doing wring when trying to import it?

**/members/backends.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
# failing to import check_password here
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_password
from members.models import Member


class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """Custom authentication backend the allows users to log in using
    their email address."""

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password=None):
        """Authentication method."""
        try:
            member = Member.objects.get(email=email)
            if member.check_password(password):
                return member
        except Member.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**mebers/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login, authenticate, logout as django_logout

from members.forms.login import LoginForm
from members.forms.register import RegisterForm

def login(request):
    """Login view."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = LoginForm()

    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        member = authenticate(email=request.POST.get('email'),
                              password=request.POST.get('password1'))
        if member is not None:
            if member.is_active:
                django_login(request,  member)
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render_to_response('members/login.html', {
        'form': form
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Did you upgrade from pre-1.9 django to 1.9 or later? It looks like the stand-alone check_password function was removed from django.contrib.auth.models. It's still available (in 1.9 at least) from django.contrib.auth.hashers, but it is probably better to call the User-object's check_password method.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem a bit confused about functions and methods. `check_password` is a method on the auth.models.User class; you can't just import it on its own. And you don't use it anyway; you call the - completely separate - `check_password` method on your own Member class; there's no need to import anything else there.

Comment: At least as recently as django 1.8, check_password was implemented as a stand-alone method in django.contrib.auth.hashers, and imported into django.contrib.auth.models: from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
    check_password, is_password_usable, make_password,
), so your somewhat snarky answer is a bit mis-placed.